# How to publish python package to Artifactory PyPi using JFrog CLI?

Tags: python, artifactory, pypi, jfrog-cli

Assuming we have a `PyPi` repository (simple API) created in `Artifactory`. Inside of a Jenkins pipeline, it's required to use `JFrog CLI` to publish any kind of artifacts because of the security policies.

Is there a way to push a python package (`dist/tar.gz, wheel`) to the PyPi repo using JFrog CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

Configure Artifactory:

```bash
> jfrog c add
```

Configure the project's resolution repository. You shoud set the virtual repository you created.

```bash
> jfrog rt pipc
```

Install project dependencies with pip from Artifactory:

```bash
> jfrog rt pipi -r requirements.txt --build-name=my-pip-build --build-number=1 --module=jfrog-python-example
```

Package the project, create distribution archives (tar.gz and whl):

```bash
> python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

Upload the packages to the pypi repository in Artifactory:

```bash
> jfrog rt u dist/ pypi/ --build-name=my-pip-build --build-number=1 --module=jfrog-python-example
```

Collect environment variables and add them to the build info:

```bash
> jfrog rt bce my-pip-build 1
```

Publish the build info to Artifactory:

```bash
> jfrog rt bp my-pip-build 1
```

Install published package by installing it from Artifactory using pip:

```bash
> jfrog rt pip-install jfrog-python-example
```

Validate package successfully installed:

```bash
> pip show jfrog-python-example
```

More details listed in [Github jfrog/project-examples](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/python-example/pip-example).

Comment: Do you need to pip install through the `jf` command or can pip install regular and just use `jf` for uploading packages and build info?

Comment: I just opened an SO post about this. Doing the upload will cause Jfrog to nest the package under a folder named "dist" on the server which doesn't make sense: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75087181/jfrog-cli-is-nesting-pypi-packages-under-the-name-of-the-local-folder-when-uploa